# Rails model if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement, model

I'm new to rails and app development so forgive any mistakes.

I've got a model called Product which has the following (schema):

```
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "cost"
    t.boolean  "in_stock"
    t.datetime "sold_date"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "quantity"
```

I want the in_stock to return true if the quantity is greater than 1, otherwise false. I wrote the following code in the product.rb file but it doesn't seem do anything when I enter the product quantities through the console. I'm not sure if I have to link the database columns (in_stock and quantity) to the if statement or not. Or if even this is the right way to go about things. I'd be grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :company

def in_stock
    if  quantity >= 1 
        in_stock true
    else 
        in_stock false
end
```

Comment: You have to use *callbacks*.

Comment: @bsvin33t Why? I was not aware of

Comment: If misused, they create though to handle situations. Eg: Sending out emails in callbacks, **bad idea**. Anecdote I heard in one of the meetups, had something like that, and when they migrated databases and ran a rake task, flooded their users with ton of text and emails.

Comment: @bsvin33t I feel like callbacks are a powerful tool if used right. Sending out emails in a callback probably are a bad idea indeed, but still one could add checks and be careful. Also, if he wanted to keep the in_stock boolean stored in DB he might want to use a callback. They aren't always evil :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing both, `quantity` and `in_stock` in your database can result in inconsistent data:

```
+----+----------+----------+
| id | in_stock | quantity |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 |     true |        0 |
|  2 |    false |       15 |
+----+----------+----------+
```

I'd compute `in_stock` based on quantity and use an additional [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for queries:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :in_stock, -> { where('quantity > 0') }

  def in_stock?
    quantity > 0
  end
end
```

Furthermore, you should ensure that `quantity` has a default value of `0` and that it cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: that's great! How is using the scope different from just the def in_stock? thx

Comment: @Arkane55 the scope is used for queries, e.g. `Product.in_stock.where(...)`, and the instance method is used when working with instances, e.g. `if @product.in_stock? ...`

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you don't need the boolean field `in_stock` to be present in the database, as it can be calculated.

the method has to be

```
def in_stock?
  quantity > 0
end
```

Follow the ruby conventions. And, if it can be calculated, don't store it. You will have to deal with issues of stale data. And generally, as a rule of thumb, try to avoid callbacks as much as possible. If you have to use it, make sure that it is modifying the state of the `self` and not some other object.

Answer (score 0):

That's not returning true, you probably accidentally wrote `in_stock true`. Try changing it to this:

```
def in_stock?
    quantity > 0
end
```

Edit: Also it looks like you want to actually set the in_stock variable. You could try something like:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_update :update_in_stock

  def update_in_stock
    if quantity > 0 
        in_stock = true
    end
  end

end
```

Edit: bsvin33t's solution also works, however if you are making this model for something that depends on the boolean being present (as you provided in your original code), then I would stick with the above code. If not, then use the method I provide at the top of this post and just remove your DB field.

Comment: @user2752843 I tried your solution but I'm still getting in_stock: null when i've updated the quantity. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: @njny use the `before_validate` callback and use `update_attributes(in_stock: true)` in the callback method.  @Arkane55